# How to use key prefix in Spring Data Couchbase with CouchbaseTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-couchbase

In a Spring Data Couchbase application, I have configured a CouchbaseTemplate bean to use a key prefix and delimeter:

```
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    ...

    @Override
    @Bean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_TEMPLATE)
    public CouchbaseTemplate couchbaseTemplate() throws Exception {
        CouchbaseTemplate couchbaseTemplate = super.couchbaseTemplate();

        couchbaseTemplate.keySettings(KeySettings.build()
            .prefix("USER")
            .delimiter("::"));

        return couchbaseTemplate;
    }

  ...
}
```

I have a document with an ID, generate from an attribute within the document, as below:

```
@Data
@Document
public class User {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES)
    private String id;

    @Field
    @IdAttribute
    private String userName;

    @Field
    private String firstName;
}
```

Then a CouchbaseRepository:

```
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "user", viewName = "all")
public interface CouchbaseUserRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<User, String> {
}
```

This is wrapped by a UserRepository implementation:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    private CouchbaseUserRepository couchbaseUserRepository;
    private CouchbaseTemplate couchbaseTemplate;

    public UserRepositoryImpl(CouchbaseUserRepository couchbaseUserRepository,
                          CouchbaseTemplate couchbaseTemplate) {
        this.couchbaseUserRepository = couchbaseUserRepository;
        this.couchbaseTemplate = couchbaseTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return couchbaseUserRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUserName(String userName) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(userName);

        String idToFind = couchbaseTemplate.getGeneratedId(user);

        return couchbaseUserRepository.findOne(idToFind);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        couchbaseUserRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

And the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {
    private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup()  {
        userRepository.deleteAll();
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(USERNAME);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(USERNAME);
        user.setFirstName("Fred");
        userRepository.save(user);

    }

}
```

When I run the test, I end up with two documents in my bucket:

```
USER::USER::username{"firstName":"Fred","_class":"com.example.couchbase.resiliency.User","userName":"username"}
USER::username{"userName":"username","_class":"com.example.couchbase.resiliency.User"}
```

It seems like when the test loads the entity, the object obviously had an ID. However, when it is saved again, the key prefix is added again prior to saving, meaning a second document is saved because this new ID does not exist.

- How can I stop the key prefix from being added twice?
- Is there a more elegant way of implementing the findByUserName
  method? From reading the Spring Data Couchbase documents, it seems
  like you have to ask the CouchbaseTemplate to generate the ID for
  you, prior to passing this to the Couchbase Repository findOne
  method.

For information, I am using Spring Data Couchbase v 2.2.18 in a Spring Boot 1.5.19 application.

Comment: Any reason you're defining the prefix and the delimiter on the template? Try to define them only on the `User` object like so `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES, delimiter = "::")` `@IdPrefix
    private final String idPrefix = "USER";`

Comment: We'd tried this and it didn't work, but we've tried again and managed to get it working. We'd obviously done something wrong with that solution. Having a bad day :) Thanks